# Using pandas dataframe columns and cells to feed into a request

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    userName  _2643698_1  _2643699_1  _2643700_1  _2643701_1  _2643702_1  
    _test2         5.0         4.8        3.75         3.6         2.2   
    _test3         4.0         5.0        4.40         5.0         5.0   
    _test4         5.0         4.4        5.00         5.0         4.0
```

Three unique users, 5 unique columns that correspond to the users, and a unique score per column/per user. 
I need to feed this data into a patch request with this logic:

Per username, update each key (column title) with the score for that user.

Example:

```
patch = change_data(userName, colId, score)
```

The goal being to update the data for all three users, each having a score in the same 5 columns (the column headers like _263698_1, with the score the user has in that column).

The real dataset I'm wrestling with has 78 users and 14 unique columns with scores for each user.

I have been playing around with a lot of options suggested on the web to get the logic I need as efficiently as possible, and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `melt()`

```
new_df = pd.melt(id_vars='userName', 
                 var_name='colId', 
                 value_vars=[c for c in df.columns if c != 'userName']
         )
```

So new_df looks like this

```
   userName       colId  value
0    _test2  _2643698_1   5.00
1    _test3  _2643698_1   4.00
2    _test4  _2643698_1   5.00
3    _test2  _2643699_1   4.80
4    _test3  _2643699_1   5.00
5    _test4  _2643699_1   4.40
6    _test2  _2643700_1   3.75
7    _test3  _2643700_1   4.40
8    _test4  _2643700_1   5.00
9    _test2  _2643701_1   3.60
10   _test3  _2643701_1   5.00
11   _test4  _2643701_1   5.00
12   _test2  _2643702_1   2.20
13   _test3  _2643702_1   5.00
14   _test4  _2643702_1   4.00
```

Then you can iterate over new_df and call change_data on each row

```
for row in new_df.itertuples(index=False):
    patch = change_data(row.userName, row.colId, row.value)
    # do something with patch
```